# Organizing a site Admin section - User section MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m building a site with ASP.NET MVC3 and would like you input on what’s the best approach to organizing the site’s sections. Is it better to have a different project for the admin part? So it could be available like admin.example.com. Or maybe just use some routing so the admin controllers go to www.example.com/admin/controller (using the Area feature)? Any thoughts? Are there any security implications to take into account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the admin section in its own area. If you then use the built in [Membership and Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) functionality, you can use the `Authorize` attribute on your controllers and/or action methods to restrict access to an administrator role. I don't think there's much to be gained by having a separate project.

As for security issues, make sure you are using HTTPS for anything that requires authentication. If you write your own membership provider, **do not** store passwords in plaintext. Use a cryptographic hash function like [BCrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx). That's just the tip of the iceberg, there are plenty of other security topics here if you do a search.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Idsa that moving it to another project is possible, but doesn't really do anything for you.  I would consider using an Area.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can move it to another project or not (I wouldn't do it) but a special admin project won't solve rights separation problem: different parts of admin should be accessed by different users.